# Multi Tenancy Support with JPA 2 and EJB 3

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, glassfish

I am trying to change Java EE web application that use JPA2 and EJB3 to support multi tenancy.

I would like to make the setting of the current tenant id before my application request start so the application itself will not have to know it is used in multi tenant environment.

I am trying not to use vendor specific feature to allow myself deploy the application to both on-prem container and google AppEngine. That been said, if I can use vendor specific feature from external place such as servlet filter this will be great solution.

I am currently using Glassfish 3.1 as container and Hibernate 4.0 as JPA2 provider.

Sample code will be much appreciated.

Thank you,
Ido.

Comment: What do you mean "multi-tenancy" ? deployment to different datastores? or deployment for multiple tenants to one datastore? Obviously "multi-tenancy" is only a feature of (unreleased) JPA2.1

Comment: @DataNucleus I think Ido is referring to the Hibernate support for multi-tenancy which has existed for quite some time now.  Correct Ido?

Comment: I mean deploy one application and one database to be used by multiple unrelated customers. Each customer need to see as if the application and database are his and his alone.

Comment: OK, thx for the clarification. Just that you mention GAE, and also Hibernate ... hence two different *types* of datastores. Obviously DataNucleus JPA (what GAE JPA uses) also provides multitenancy support (for BigTable, as well as for all other supported datastores)

Comment: Yes, it is two different data access. It looks like both EclipseLink and Hibernate implement multi tenant support but JPA standard is left behind. I'll have to use vedor specific solution until the standard will be updated. J2EE 7 maybe...  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPA does not define any specific multi-tenancy support.  So it may be difficult to implement without using a provider specific feature.

You could have the same tables for each tenant, but in a different schema.  You could then have a different persistence unit that had the same mappings, but set a different default schema in an additional orm.xml file.

For the multi-tenancy support in Glassfish through EclipseLink see,

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Advanced_JPA_Development/Single-Table_Multi-Tenancy

Comment: Thank you. I've read and understand the 3 strategies of separate database, separate schema and discriminator column. I would like to go with the discriminator because it the most scalable. I agree that it seem I have to use provider specific approach. Because I'm using Hibernate I'll try to make it work with it and only if I fail I'll go to EclipseLink. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would use two databases for multi tenancy. This way, maintenance remains simpler. You can store an indicator in thread local and check it during runtime to decide what connection to use.